# Assign name from property to object

Tags: html, typescript

I'm trying to create an object that takes its name from another property.

```
const slide = 0;
const result = 'Hello';
const object = { slide: result };

How I want the object to look like in the end:
{ 0: result }
```

How can I achieve this? Because the way I use it, the name will always be "slide", but I want it to take the 0 as a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
const object = { [slide]: result };
```

or another way to do this is:

```
const object = {};
object[slide] = result;
```